# How Do I Configure the Gremlin Console to AWS Neptune?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have downloaded the `Apache Tinkerpop Gremlin Console` but I cannot figure out how to connect this to my AWS Neptune Instance. Please provide me with step by step instructions to get this connected to the Neptune.

Answer (score 0):

The official procedure is provided from AWS here -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-console.html

1. Please be aware that by default, your Neptune instance does not permit a remotely accessible port. That has to be prepared via an Application Load Balancer or having the AWS VPN connection to your VPC. For this reason, I highly recommend that you launch a small Linux instance on your VPC and SSH to this to follow the instructions first. You will also need to install Java 8 or later on that machine. If using a VPN, you would also ensure that the inbound traffic to port 8182 be enabled on the VPC's subnet(s) that's serviced by the AWS Open VPN endpoint. These are not the only options but are answered elsewhere.
2. Download the AWS CA Certificate from https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem. It will come up as a text on your browser. Just copy and paste as something like `aws.pem` This is to allow TLS connection from the Gremlin Console.
3. Using `openssl` tool (installone if you don't have it.) export this `pem` to `p12` file.  p12 or pkcs12 is the format the Java Certificat Store recognizes. It would go like this:

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -out aws.p12 -in aws.pem
   ```
4. From here on I have `cd` to the root of the gremlin console distribution.
5. Copy above aws.p12 under the `conf` directory.
6. Obtain the full DNS address of your Neptune instance from your AWS Console
7. Open conf/remote.yaml and use the following pattern example to edit the host and add connectionPool configuration.

   ```
   hosts: [test.cluster-abcdefzxyz.planet-earth-1.neptune.amazonaws.com]
   connectionPool: { enableSsl: true,  trustStore: conf/aws.p12 }
   ```
8. Create a file conf/remote.txt with the following lines. This is an optional step but otherwise, you will be typing thses two `:remote` commands each time you start the console.

   ```
   :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
   :remote console
   ```
9. Finally issue the following line on your terminal.

   ```
   cd bin
   gremlin.bat -i conf/remote.txt
   ```
10. The gremlin console should start, connect to the Neptune and be ready to accept your Gremlin queries. To quickly test this.

    g.V().limit(1)

Comment: Official doc on this process here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-console.html  Note: You shouldn't need to download and configure the SSL cert so long as the machine where you are installing Gremlin Console has Internet access. Neptune uses a public CA for its certs, so the Console should be able to verify Neptune's cert if it can reach the Internet.

Comment: That's great to hear that the official document will be there. As for the CA Cert, I did this on my Windows 11 machine, and it would not connect without that CA referenced directly. Likely this is because I use the VPN and go to the .internal.

Comment: Please also see the "An alternate way to connect to the Gremlin console" section [at this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-console.html). I find that a much more powerful way to use the Gremlin Console with a remote server.

Comment: VPN makes sense.  Unless you had you're VPN connection configured for split-tunnel, it is likely you wouldn't have the ability to connect to a public CA.

Comment: As for the CA it is certainly in the Windows certificate store or in Key Chain but Java does not refer to them and need a manual step to add it in the Java's cert store or do it locally like I wrote. At least that's how it is on my machine.